# Modifying SSL / TLS certificates for local use

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, tls

I am currently developing some applications on my local 'serverfarm'.
I have set up `ZendServer` with `Apache2` and `PHP`, which works very fine, and nothing unwanted happened until now:

Now I wanted to manage my `MySQL` databases with `phpMyAdmin`, because `Sun's` MySQL SQL tool seems to cause problems creating valid batches.

Working with PMA is not the problem, I am extremely used to work with PMA, **if I could access it**.

And this is my actual problem: **My Firefox wants to tell me that he can not open a 'self-signed certificate'.**
I tried to work-around that by editing Firefox's ssl configurations, but it did NOT seem to work.

Now I have to change the servers' certificates, but I did not where to find the specific file, because I never had to worry about ssl or tls configurations.

Answer (score 1):

When Firefox, or any other browser, has a problem with a certificate (expired, self-signed, invalid domain, etc) there is a dialog where you can add a security exception.  You should be able to add a permanent exception for the warning.

If you continue to have issue, why not disable SSL?  If it's just local development, what's the risk?

Comment: The problem is, that PMA is only reachable via https:// . This is ZendServer's security standard.

Comment: and by the way, I am sorry, but if I add localhost or any internal ethernet ip to the exceptions firefox still kicks me.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to add it to any exceptions list in the options, but when you actually hit the page.  In my firefox (3.0.x on Linux) it says: 

"Secure Connection Failed
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
etc.."

At the bottom is a blue link "Or you can add an exception..." - Is this what you are doing?

Comment: No, it says: (US) http://bit.ly/3Be37B (EU) http://imagr.eu/upload/issuer.png "self-signed etc. etc."

Answer (score 1):

[This is the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275237/in-firefox-can-i-disable-the-website-certified-by-an-unknown-authority-ssl-cer/418589#418589).

I found this solution while cruising through stackoverflow.com

Thank you anyway.